# How to select a case with sum operator in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query that sums values from different columns when they have a id active like id_test = 1 note_test = 11, it has a case stament if the id is in 0

this is the query

```
select                                              
    case when id_test1 = 1 then note_test1 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test2 = 1 then note_test2 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test3 = 1 then note_test3 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test4 = 1 then note_test4 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test5 = 1 then note_test5 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test6 = 1 then note_test6 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test7= 1 then note_test7 else 0 end as total_weighted                                              
    from rp_student where id = 1
```

This is my query in laravel

```
$weighted= DB::table('rp_student')
        ->select(DB::raw('case when id_test1 = 1 then note_test1 else 0 end +                                               
    case when id_test2 = 1 then note_test2 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test3 = 1 then note_test3 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test4 = 1 then note_test4 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test5 = 1 then note_test5 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test6 = 1 then note_test6 else 0 end +                                             
    case when id_test7= 1 then note_test7 else 0 end as total_weighted'))
        ->where('id','=',1);
```

It doesn't return me any value

Comment: try to add a `->get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is missing the required `->get()` at the end. The reason why your don't see a value currently is the query hasn't actually been executed.

> The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP stdClass object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results